# Example of a semiconcave, but not concave function

Tags: real-analysis

If we define the semiconcave function by requiring a constant $C>0$ to exist, such that for all $x,\lambda\in \mathbb{R}^d$, the following is true:
$$ f(x+\lambda)-2f(x)+f(x-\lambda)\le C|\lambda|^2,$$
then what function can be given as an example of a semiconcave, but not concave?

Comment: $f(x) = x^2$...

Comment: @Rigel I was thinking about this example, but then I was kinda lost understanding the definition. $x^2$ is a convex function, right? Is there any connection between semiconcavity and concavity then?

Comment: A (locally) semiconcave function can be written as the sum of a regular ($C^2$) function and a concave function. So, for example, $f(x) = x^2 - |x|$ is semiconcave.